# Exported PDFs from Mathematica 8 won't print

Tags: pdf, export, wolfram-mathematica

UPDATE: I wrote to Wolfram support about this and will update the post if they can resolve the problem. Sorry for spamming SO with a technical support question, but here it remains in case anyone else is having the same issue.

Is anyone else having this problem with Mathematica 8? I recently upgraded and noticed that when I export Graphics to a PDF file, although the file appears fine on my computer, it prints as a blank page. For example, try

```
Rectangle[{1,1}]//
Graphics//
Export["~/test.pdf",#]&
```

which creates a PDF file containing a black square. This file opens fine, but if I send it to my department printer I just get a blank page. If I don't export the graphics but print the notebook from MM, no problem, the graphics print as expected. If I use MM 7 to do exactly the same thing, the PDF file prints as expected. Exporting to PNG in MM8 seems to work fine. And, using the context menu `Save Graphics As ...` or `File > Save Selection As ...` to create a PDF containing just the graphic also works. However, these graphics eventually get included in a TeX document, and it would be far better if I could continue using the script I've got that doesn't require any button clicking to generate them.

I'm running MM 8.0.0.0 on Mac OS 10.6.7. I have not been able to test this on another printer yet, but this printer has never given me problems before and prints other PDF documents fine. Any ideas why this is happening?

Wolfram Research responds:

> ...
>   This issue has been reported by other users as
>   well and our developers are currently looking into it. I have added your
>   details to the report so you can be notified when this is resolved.
>
> In the meantime, the alternatives that you could try are:
>
> 1. Try a different printer.
> 2. Rasterize the image with the function 'Rasterize' before exporting. If
>      the rasterized image loses some resolution, you could use the option
>      'ImageResolution' to edit this.
>
> Rasterize[image, ImageResolution -> xxx]

Comment: @Closers: This IS a programming question! The OP needs to print FROM a program

Comment: I can reproduce the described behavior, and I think support@wolfram.com should definitely be made aware of the problem.

Comment: What is the ultimate use of the PDF?  `NotebookPrint[...]` to send the graphic straight to the printer works for me.

Comment: No problem here: mma8.01 win7-64, printing to an old Apple Laserwriter Select 360.

Comment: @Brett: the PDFs are figures that ultimately get used in a TeX document, which is why I'm trying to find out if there's a way to get this working with Export as opposed to File > Save As... or NotebookPrint. Thanks, though, and I will email Wolfram; don't know why I didn't think of that first.

Comment: @belisarius: That was unnecessary. OP is not new to SO... He's been here for 5 months (longer than me or Mr. W or SCdV), he has answered some questions and has accepted an answer on his only other question.

Comment: @yoda I saw that, but if you check his comments under ragfield's answer, you may see he is having doubts about how to handle some situations. Anyway, my message is not aggressive nor rep hunting, isn't it?

Comment: @belisarius: your comment below was good :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Surely this is a bug (please report it to support@wolfram.com), but you can work around the problem by selecting the graphic and choosing File > Save Selection As... from the menu (or Save Graphic As... from the contextual menu).  This produces a slightly different file that doesn't appear to exhibit the undesirable behavior we observe from Export[].

Comment: That's a good point; I should have reported this to Wolfram. My apologies! What's the right way to handle this on SO, should I just delete my post?

Comment: @DGrady  No, don't delete it. It may be useful for others. Accept this answer if it is useful, and upvote it if you consider it worth the vote. I'll post some instructions for you in a moment

Comment: I'm having the same issue with PDFs produced with > Save Selection As... PDF on a Mac (Mma 8.0.1) and then (not) printed to a HP Color Laser Jet from Windows XP. So maybe it's not just the method used to produce the PDFs, but some weird printer driver thing? Or a Mac OS X thing? The error messages I get are "A printing error occurred", followed by "No pages were selected to print", followed by "A drawing error occurred."

Answer (score 1):

These problematic files, and LaTeX PDFs that include them, can be properly printed by Adobe Reader 10.1.2. That's if you're okay with installing and using a 450MB PDF reader.

I reproduced the problem (leading me to this question) with Mathematica 8.0.4.0 on Mac OS X 10.7.2. Wolfram suggested lame workarounds like `Rasterize` and told me

> This issue has been addressed by our developers, and a fix will be included in a future version of Mathematica.